# Kubernete nginx ingress passthrough

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a springboot Application

I secured it by using spring security and X509 authentication as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.1/reference/html5/#servlet-x509)

So far, so good... all works as a charm. I tested my application an it accepts only SSL connection and can manage successfully the X509 certificate in the `HttpServletRequest` attribute `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate`. No HTTP connection is allowed.

Now I need to deploy it ad kubernetes app and I'm trying to configure my ingress in order to use passthrough

This is my `ingress.yaml`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-name-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /eid-tsl/
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - x509.auth.it
  rules:
  - host: x509.auth.it
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: x509-service
          servicePort: 443
```

This is my `service.yaml`

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: x509-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: eid-tls
  ports:
  #- protocol: TCP
  #  name: http-port
  #  port: 80
  #  targetPort: 9292
  - protocol: TCP
    name: https-port
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8443
```

When I try to access to the site I receive a 502 Bad Gateway error. If I remove the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"` I have the error showed in the following figure

[image: Bad Request]

May anybody tell me how I can successfully configure my ingress as passthrough?

Thank you

Angelo

**UPDATE** Added `deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: eid-tls-deployment
  labels:
    app: eid-tls
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eid-tls
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eid-tls
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: eid-tls
        image: my-image:10
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8443
        #- containerPort: 9191
```

Comment: Where is your cluster? Cloud or local environment? Do you have more Ingresses or only nginx ingress? Did you try to add annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` ? Could you also share your deployment yaml?

Comment: I added the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`. I added my `deployment.yaml` as you required. My cluster is in my client environment and it’s a private environment

Comment: How did you deploy `Nginx Ingress`, did you specify `--enable-custom-resources` and `--enable-tls-passthrough` ? Do you have in your `Nginx Ingress Controller` in `spec.containers.args:` parameter like `--enable-ssl-passthrough` ?